# Copy files and folders of directory older than certain range of date using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I need to move all the files and subsequent folders of source directory to the destination directory and then delete from the source folder in a specific given range of dates.

**for example:**

```
start date = 04/01/2021
end date = 04/30/2021
```

but i am having difficulties after few lines of code .its not working .

**my batch script so far**

```
set "Sourcefolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\SourceFile"
set "Destfolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\DestFile"
set _NoOfDays=30
robocopy /S /MINAGE:%_NoOfDays% "%Sourcefolder%" "%Destfolder%" /E 
echo File copied Successful^>^>%Sourcefolder%>>%Destfolder%
d /d %Sourcefolder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

this seems to for no of days not range of date and also I need to delete the files too after copying which I am not able to achieve in delete part of script  .any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I would just go the powershell route here, it is standard on your system, just [script it](https://markb.uk/powershell-copy-files-modified-between-dates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with [FileTimeFilterJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat):

```
set "Sourcefolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\SourceFile"
set "Destfolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\DestFile"
set "begin_date=01-04-21#00:00:00"
set "end_date=30-04-21#59:00:00"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (
  'FileTimeFilterJS.bat "%Sourcefolder%" -beginDate %begin_date% -endDate %end_date%'
) do (
   copy "%%~fa" "%Destfolder%" /Y
)
```